# Is a covered sukkah wall counted as a wall?

Tags: halacha, sukkah

There's a foot of roof overhanging one side of my sukkah. I know that the space inside the sukkah under that roof is not kosher for fulfillment of one's sukkah obligation. I'm wondering about the status of the wall on that side. Since the [sechach](http://www.ou.org/chagim/sukkot/sechach.htm) adjacent to that wall is all invalidated by the covering, does that make the wall invalid as well?

This doesn't affect the overall validity of my sukkah, since I have three other walls that are not covered, but I'm curious about the rules involved. If you have too much of the perimeter of your Sukkah covered, does that invalidate the middle as well?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe the rule is "Dofen Akuma" ("crooked wall") -- vis-a-vis wall count, we view the wall as reaching the schach past the overhang.

Comment: Oh, right. So, the Sechach under the overhand is considered to be part of the adjacent wall?

Comment: Dofen Akuma is explained here: http://www.shemayisrael.com/yomtov/sukkot/laws.htm