# How far does dofen akuma stretch?

Tags: halacha, shiurim-measurements, sukkah, schach, dofen-akuma

After reading [Is a covered sukkah wall counted as a wall?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/2909/5151) i had a followup question on the answer there. (I was actually going to ask that, and had even drawn up diagrams, only to find that it was already asked. :()

How far can the wall be from the schach for *dofen akuma* to apply?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Shulchan Aruch in [סימן תרלב - דברים הפוסלים בסכך](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01975_part_36.html#HtmpReportNum0007_L2) says:

> **א** סְכָךְ פָּסוּל, פּוֹסֵל בָּאֶמְצַע בְּד' טְפָחִים; אֲבָל פָּחוֹת מִד', כְּשֵׁרָה, וּמֻתָּר לִישַׁן תַּחְתָּיו **מִן הַצַּד אֵינוֹ פּוֹסֵל אֶלָּא בְּד' אַמּוֹת, אֲבָל פָּחוֹת מִד' אַמּוֹת, כְּשֵׁרָה דְּאָמְרִינָן דֹּפֶן עֲקֻמָּה**, דְּהַיְנוּ לוֹמַר שֶׁאָנוּ רוֹאִים כְּאִלּוּ הַכֹּתֶל נֶעֱקָם וְיֵחָשֵׁב זֶה הַסְכָךְ הַפָּסוּל מִגּוּף הַכֹּתֶל, וְדָבָר זֶה הֲלָכָה לְמֹשֶׁה מִסִינַי. הִילְכָּךְ בַּיִת שֶׁנִּפְחַת בָּאֶמְצַע וְסִכֵּךְ בִּמְקוֹם הַפְּחָת וְנִשְׁאַר מִן הַתִּקְרָה סָבִיב בֵּין סְכָךְ כָּשֵׁר לַכְּתָלִים פָּחוֹת מֵאַרְבַּע אַמּוֹת, כְּשֵׁרָה, וּמִיהוּ אֵין יְשֵׁנִים תַּחְתָּיו כָּל זְמַן שֶׁיֵּשׁ בּוֹ אַרְבָּעָה טְפָחִים.‏

You have up to 4 Amot for דֹּפֶן עֲקֻמָּה to apply.

However, it must not be emtpty space, (air) but something physical. Air makes the Sukka Pasul at 3 tefachim, already

> **ב** אֲוִיר, בֵּין בִּגְדוֹלָה בֵּין בִּקְטַנָּה שָׁוִים, דְּבֵין בָּאֶמְצַע בֵּין מִן הַצַּד בְּג' טְפָחִים פְּסוּלָה, בְּפָחוֹת מִג' כְּשֵׁרָה‏

Answer (score 3):

Four cubits, about 1.92 meters. See [here](http://www.shemayisrael.com/yomtov/sukkot/laws.htm) in section E3.

Comment: (Note there are opinions that four cubits is about 1.82-2.30 meters as well.)